# DataTables 1.9 Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

We are trying to use the Buttons extension with DataTables 1.9 so that we can get away from the antiquated Flash version used by the TableTools extension. However, I keep getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
at datatables-buttons.min.js:83
at datatables-buttons.min.js:5
at datatables-buttons.min.js:5
```

Is the Buttons extension just not compatible with DataTables 1.9? We'd like to try to avoid having to do the full upgrade to 1.10 if possible as it has many changes that we'd have to implement in order to do so. Ideally we can get an Html5 implementation that works with DataTables 1.9.

Comment: "*Is the Buttons extension just not compatible with DataTables 1.9?*". No. It is not so hard to upgrade, did it myself some while ago with a really, really old website, exactly because flash becomes more and more outdated (and completely lacking in browsers like chromium) . It took only an hour or so, and I had a lot of old 1.9.1 (!!) code. I had feared that it would be complicated, but it is worth investing the little time to do it.

Comment: @davidkonrad, please post your comment as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks for replying.